# Solving least squares problem using partial derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, least-squares, projection

Let's say we want to solve a linear regression problem by choosing the best slope and bias with the least squared errors. As example, let the points be $x=[1, 2, 3]$ and $y=[1,2,2]$.

This quadratic minimization problem can also be represented as:

$||Ax-b||^2=||e||^2=e^2_1+e^2_2+e^2_3$

## Linear Algebra

We could solve this problem by utilizing linear algebraic methods. We could use projections. For projecting on the $0+$ dimensional subspaces. Projection equation $p = Ax = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ could be utilized:

$A^T(b-Ax)=0$

$A^TAx = A^Tb$

$x = (A^TA)^{-1} A^Tb$

We know the inner product of $A^T$ and $e=b-p=b-Ax$ is $0$ since they are orthogonal (or since $e$ is in the null space of $A^T$). Which is the reason why we got the equation above.

Now we need to present the quadratic minimization problem in linear algebra $Ax=b$:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c \\m\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$

where $c$ is bias and $m$ is slope. We can see that matrix $A$ is a basis for the column space, $c$ and $m$ are linear coefficients and $b$ represents range of the function. Considering that this equation doesn't have direct solution, then we are looking for projection of the vector $b$ on the column space of matrix $A$.

**Solution**:

Let $Proj(x)$ be the projection function (where $x$ contains unknown coefficients that we are trying to find, in this case $[c, m]^T$):

$Proj(x) = Proj\left(\begin{bmatrix}c \\ m \end{bmatrix}\right) = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb = \left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 &  3\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\  2\\ \end{bmatrix} = \left(\begin{bmatrix}3 & 6 \\ 6 & 14 \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix}=\left(\frac{1}{3(14)-6(6)}\begin{bmatrix}14 & -6 \\ -6 & 3  \end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2.33333333 & -1 \\ -1 & 0.5  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.66666667 \\ 0.5 \end{bmatrix}$

## Multivariable Calculus

[At this point of the lecture](https://youtu.be/osh80YCg_GM?t=1510) Professor Strang presents the minimization problem as $A^TAx=A^Tb$ and shows the normal equations. Then he proceeds solving minimization problem using partial derivatives, although I couldn't quite understand how could partial differentiation be used to solve this problem.

From what I know, partial derivatives can be used to find derivatives for the structures that are in higher dimensions. Since for example finding full derivative at certain point of a 3 dimensional object may not be possible since it can have infinite tangent lines. Although, by treating one variable as a constant can be utilized to solve the differentiation problem, and this process is called partial differentiation from my knowledge.

## Question

How does partial differentiation solution exactly work? How can it be compared to the linear algebraic orthogonal projection solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Relevant: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To try to answer your question about the connection between the partial derivatives method and the method using linear algebra, note that for the linear algebra solution, we want $$(Ax-b)\cdot Ax = 0$$.
For the partial derivatives, we want $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}||Ax-b||^2 = 0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}||Ax-b||^2 = 0$.  Suppose we have $n$ data points and $n$ inputs $a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n$.  Then, with $x_1$ representing the slope of the least squares, and $x_2$ representing the intercept, we have that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}||Ax-b||^2 = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i(x_1a_i+x_2-b_i) = 0$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}||Ax-b||^2 = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_1a_i+x_2-b_i) = 0$$.  This implies that $$x_1\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i(x_1a_i+x_2-b_i)+x_2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_1a_i+x_2-b_i) = 0$$
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_1a_i+x_2)(x_1a_i+x_2-b_i)=0=Ax\cdot (Ax-b)$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for the question! So as I understand the goal here is to find local minimum? Therefore the partial derivative of quadratic error function with respect to $x$ is equal to the sum of squared error that our matrix can span as well. But apologies for my confusion, why are there two partial derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the least squares minimization problem 
$$\min_{x} ||Ax-b||$$ by setting the partial derivatives of the cost function (wrt each element of x)
$$f(x) = ||Ax-b||$$ equal to zero.  You will get $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns, where $n$ is the dimension of the least squares solution vector $x$.  It can be shown that the solution x is a local minimum.

By using least squares to fit data to a model, you are assuming that any errors in your data are additive and Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

You have a matrix $A$ with 2 columns -- one column of ones, and one column the vector $x$ (in your case $x=[1, 2, 3]^T$. You are looking for vector of parameters $p=[c, m]^T$. For given parameters $p$ the vector $Ap$ is the vector of values $c+mx_i$, and the vector $e=Ap-y^T$ is the vector of errors of you model $(c+mx_i)-y_i$. Now the sum of squares of errors is $f(p)=|Ap-y|^2$, and this is what you want to minimize, by varying $p$.  The basic idea is to find extrema of $f(p)$ by setting $f$s derivative (with respect to $p$) to zero. It will turn out that if not all $x_i$ are equal, this local extremum is unique, and is in fact a global minimum. Leaving that aside for a moment, we focus on finding the local extremum.

We can do it in at least two ways. The higher-brow way is to say that for $g(z)= |z|^2$ one has $Dg(z)=2z^T$ (since $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} \sum z_i^2=2 z_i$), and so, since $D (Ap)=A$ at every point $p$, by chain rule $D(|Ap-y|^2)=2(Ap-y)^T A$. Thus the optimality equation is $(Ap-y)^T A=0$, as in the linear algebra approach.

The lower-tech method is to just compute the partials with respect to $c$ and $m$.

For partial in $c$:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial c} \sum_i [(c+mx_i)-y_i]^2=\sum_i 2[(c+mx_i)-y_i]=2(Ap-y)\cdot [1, \ldots, 1]^T=0$

For partial in $m$:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \sum_i [(c+mx_i)-y_i]^2=\sum_i 2 [(c+mx_i)-y_i] x_i =2(Ap-y)\cdot x=0$

Setting both to zero we get two equations expressing the fact that the two columns of $A$ are orthogonal to $(Ap-y)$, which is again the same as $(Ap-y)^TA=0$.

Thus the optimization approach is equivalent to the linear algebra one.

Now about the nature of local optimum.

From general theory: The function $f(p)$ is quadratic in $p$ with positive-semidefinite leading term $A^TA$
If $x$ is not proportional to the vector of 1s, this leading term is positive definite, and so the function is strictly convex and hence has a unique global minimum.

Alternatively: If $x$ is not proportional to the vector of 1s, then rank of $A$ is 2, and $A$ has no null space. Then $|Ap|$ is never zero, and so attains a minimum on the unit circle. Then for $p$ with large $|p|$ we have that $|Ap|$ is large, hence so is  $|Ap-y|$.  On the other hand, the set of solutions of $(Ap-y)^TA=0$ aka of $A^T(Ap-y)=0$ aka $A^TAp=A^Ty$ is an affine subspace on which the value of $f(p)$ is therefore constant. This can work only if this space is of dimension 0 - otherwise as we go to infinity inside this subspace the value $f(p)$ would have to grow unbounded while staying constant. So in fact there is precisely one solution, and hence (since the function grows to positive infinity at infinity) it is a global minimum, just as expected.